# How to handle Encoding for < or > type of string using Regular expression in C# 2.0

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-2.0

Below is the regular expression written in C#2.0 code for removing unwanted querystring (anything present in excludeList) will be excluded from page querystring and it is working fine for me.

```
string querystring = string.Empty;                       
string excludeList = "cid,incid,h";                        
querystring = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query, @"^\?", "&"), "&(" + excludeList.Replace(",", "|") + ")=[^&]*", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), "^&", "?");
```

Now I want to modify my regular expresion so that if my excludeList contain as below, would encode if there is any < or > in my page querystring.

```
string excludeList = "cid,incid,h,<,>";
```

For example if my page querystring contains something  then it should be encoded to proper #343script#545 (example)

Please suggest what modification needs to be done for handling encoding.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Say

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query = "http://localhost:80/faq.aspx?faqid=123&cid=5434&des=dxb&incid=6565&data=<sam>";
string excludeList = "cid,incid,h,<,>";
```

Now my above regular expresion when applied on above querystring variable it will render out as below

```
string querystring = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query, @"^\?", "&"), "&(" + excludeList.Replace(",", "|") + ")=[^&]*", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), "^&", "?");

querystring = "?faqid=123&des=dxb&data=%3C%20sam%20%3E";
```

Now above everything works fine, I want to encode "<" and ">" using above regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
(?is)^(?<del>[^\?]+?)(?<retain>\?.+)$
```

**Explanation**

```
@"
(?is)         # Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i); dot matches newline (s)
^             # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?<del>       # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “del”
   [^\?]         # Match any character that is NOT a ? character
      +?            # Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
)
(?<retain>    # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “retain”
   \?            # Match the character “?” literally
   .             # Match any single character
      +             # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
$             # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

**update code**

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?is)^(?<del>[^?]+?)(?<retain>\?.+)$", "${retain}");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: @how to use above regex in my existing regular expression, I want to hanlde in my existing regex and please suggest how to handle encoding for < and >

Comment: What will be the value of subjectString, and what about my existing regex for removing the querystring from querystring..please suggest

Comment: I can't see the encoding handling for < and >, so you mean I don't have to use my regular expression I should go with your Regex and also after applying the regex how the updated value will be stored back to my querystring variable

Comment: Updated the question, please see the EDIT section.

Comment: I really don't understand were is encoding handling in your solution as I have asked < should be converted to its appropriate encoding..Please suggest whether i need to use my existing regular expression or use your one only, but still no encoding handling